# NoSuchMethodError: <init> when using rJava to create a new object

Tags: java, r, exception, rjava

Recently I came across a problem when using rJava.
First I create a public class DirectedEdge:

```
public class DirectedEdge {
    public int v;
    public int w;
    public double weight;
    public DirectedEdge(){}
    public DirectedEdge(int v, int w, double weight) {
        this.v = v;
        this.w = w;
        this.weight = weight;
    }
}
```

Then I run the following codes on RStudio:

```
.jinit();
.jaddclassPath('XXXXXX');
.jnew('DirectedEdge');
.jnew('DirectedEdge',1,2,0.1);
```

I have already set the classpath to where my .class files are located, but the third line did run and the forth line failed. RStudio gave me an exception:

```
Error in .jnew("DirectedEdge", 1, 2, 0.1) : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: <init>
```

I also tried the example in rJava document:

```
.jnew('java/lang/String',"Hello World!")
```

It worked well. So what's the problem? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default type of the number is double, so use .jnew("DirectedEdge", as.integer(1), as.integer(2), 0.1) instead

Comment: Or use `.jnew("DirectedEdge", 1L, 2L, 0.1)`